# How to hide the empty Column

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview

Using C# & asp.net

if there is no data's in the table, gridview displaying one rows (it was empty)

I want to hide the gridview empty row.

How to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you can normally delete that one visible row just check that if a field that would normally have a value is empty and the row count is 1 then delete that row.

```
if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(mydatagrid.Rows[0][0].ToString()) && mydatagrid.Rows.Count==1) //Check a field that would normally have a value
{
     mydatagrid.Rows.RemoveAt(0);
}
```

Let me know if this helps/works

Answer (score 1):

If you are manually data binding than you can check at that time and hide or disable the control if there is no data. If you are data binding using the design view than you should subscribe to the DataBinding or the PreRender events on the control and check then.

Answer (score 1):

you can check if the datatable doesn't have any rows

use:

```
mydatagrid.DataSource=null;

mydatagrid.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

As the other two comments you can either check in code and set MyDataGrid.Visible to true or false to hide the entire table, or you can not bind the datasource, or you can EmptyDataTemplate option to display whatever you want when there is no data for the GridView to display normally.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.emptydatatemplate.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The normal behavior for GridView is to render NOTHING if there are no data rows. (Well, *almost* nothing; it insists on rendering a <div> wrapper, but that'll be empty.)

If you specify an EmptyDataTemplate, however, a one-celled wrapper table is generated to contain whatever is in your template. *Even if your template is empty*, you'll get that wrapper table (with its one cell, empty). Sounds like the answer to your question is **don't specify an EmptyDataTemplate**.

Comment: That EmptyDataTemplate table wrapper is an even more annoying presumption than the GridView div. If you want your empty GridView to look just like a data-populated one (with a footer to add new rows, for example), you create a table template... which is then uselessly wrapped in another table. Not a recipe for CSS success.